# AWS SSM AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json File Instance Name For Custom Metric

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

This block of code puts the megabytes of available memory custom metrics into CloudWatch. However I am unable to get it to post the hostname with the metrics. This block is in the AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json file within the directory:

C:\Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch\

```
{
  "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
  "Id": "MemoryAvailableMBytes",
  "Parameters": {
    "CategoryName": "Memory",
    "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
    "DimensionName": "InstanceID",
    "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}",
    "InstanceName": "",
    "MetricName": "AvailableMBytes",
    "Unit": "Megabytes"
    }
  },
```

I have attempted to use the following key pairs for InstanceName:
      "InstanceName": "{hostname}",
      "InstanceName": "{instance}",

I am making sure to restart the EC2Config service then the Amazon SSM Agent service after editing the AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json file. The "InstanceName": "{hostname}", key pair had worked in an earlier version of the JSON file. When I assign the {hostname} value to InstanceName the metrics stop being written to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

The instance name is a specific name of the perf counter that is selected and not meant for the ec2 instance. The Dimension you added should show up as the instance name.